# Why is there sometimes no "Move to trash"/"Move to bin"

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to clean up some old Google Sheets, but some of them don't have a "move to bin" menu option (on the left), other spreadsheets do have it (on the right):

[image: no "move to bin"] [image: "move to bin"]

What's the difference?

How can I delete spreadsheets that don't have the menu item?

<sub>My current work around is to use the Google Drive desktop integration, and delete them there.</sub>

Comment: How do I find out if they're old or not?

Comment: Not saved yet? Already in trash? Shared with you by someone else?

Comment: Definitely already saved (most are pretty old), not in trash. Possibly shared with me by someone else. If this last case, then how do I get rid of them out of my Drive?